# Java Play: Nested models and persistence

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, playframework

I have nested models in a very simple Play application. I have a `User` model which looks like;

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @Constraints.Email
    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    public City city;
}
```

And the `City` model looks like;

```
@Entity
public class City extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public String name;

    @ManyToOne
    public Country country;
}
```

Which is again, very simple.

I then have the `Country` model, which is;

```
@Entity
public class Country extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public String name;
}
```

Now, what I'm doing is POST-ing parameters `email`, `password`, and `city_id` to an action;

```
    public static Result registerUser() {
        Form<Register> registerForm = form(Register.class).bindFromRequest();
        Logger.debug(registerForm.toString());
        if (registerForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(register.render(registerForm));
        } else {
            User user = form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();
            user.save();
            return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.login());
        }
    }
```

The database I'm using is `MySQL`, and I can see the new `User` rows coming in. What I always see is that `city_id` stays `null` which wasn't what I had assumed.

I had assumed Hibernate to take care of the relationship between the objects and the corresponding database foreign keys, but that doesn't seem to be working.

I have a city with id = 1 entered into the `city` table already and that is the `city_id` I'm sending through `POST`.

What's going on here?

Comment: ud have to set the city object to the user for hibernate to take care of relationships user.setCity(city)

Comment: Can you be more specific @eldjon? And how will the setter method look like? Is `city` the `city_id` or the `name`?

Comment: if you want to add a User belonging to a City you would have to explicitly create the user instance lets say User u = new User() and then you should set the city instance to this user (assuming that u know the city of the user) u.setCity(city). where city is an instance of City class and can come either from db (you can find it if you have its id/name) or somehow you can create an instace if you know its id/name.

Comment: i mean just user.city = city (didnt realize it was public field :D )